# How to email an attachment from a form with GAE?

Tags: python, forms, http, google-app-engine, post

My attempt at emailing from a form gets an error message. How should I process the file with the POST request? I don't need to write it to the blobstore, just email it.

Template:

```
  <form method="POST" action="{{form_url}}" name="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
<table border="0"><tr><td colspan="2">    
 <div class="labelform">
  </div>
  <div><input type="hidden" id="lng" name="lng" size="35" maxlength="50" value="" /></div>
 <div class="labelform">    
  </div>
  <div><input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" size="35" maxlength="50" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="place" name="place" size="55" maxlength="55" value="" />
</div>           
  </td><td rowspan="9">    
  </td></tr>    
{% for field in form %}      
<tr><td>
      <div class="labelform" style="display: block;">
        <label>{% trans "Type of problem" %}:</label>
      </div>
      </td><td>   
</label>    <select name="subject" id="subject">
            <option value="{% trans "Problems with ads" %}" >{% trans "Problems with ads" %}</option>
            <option value="{% trans "Advertising" %}" >{% trans "Advertising" %}</option>
            <option value="{% trans "Images" %}" >{% trans "Images" %}</option>
            <option value="{% trans "Our rules when advertising" %}" >{% trans "Our rules when advertising" %}</option>
            <option value="{% trans "Technical problems" %}" >{% trans "Technical problems" %}</option>
            <option value="{% trans "Other" %}" >{% trans "Other" %}</option>           
            </select>
                </div>
  </td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.name.errors }}
        <label for="id_subject">{% filter capfirst %}{% trans "name" %}{% endfilter %}</label></td><td>
         <div>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="{{ user.nickname }}{% if not user %}{{ current_user.name|escape }}{% endif %}{% if not user and not current_user %}{% ifequal twittername None %}{% else %}{{ twittername }}{% endifequal %}{% endif %}" size="35" maxlength="50" />
    <div id="err_name" style="display: none;">
      <span class="warning" id="err_msg_name"></span>
    </div>
  </div></td></tr>
    </div><tr><td>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.email.errors }}
        <label for="id_sender">{% trans "E-mail address" %}</label></td><td>
        {{ form.email }}</td></tr>

    </div><tr><td valign="top">
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.text.errors }}
        <label for="id_message">{% trans "Text" %}</label></td><td>
        {{ form.text }}</td></tr>
    </div>
    </div>
  <tr><td> </td><td> <input type="file" name="file" /><br>{% trans "If there is a problem with the images - upload them here" %}<br/>   
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> </td></tr></table>
```

Code:

```
class ContactFileUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):#to do:attachment
    def post(self):
        message = mail.EmailMessage(sender='admin@appspotapp-id.com', subject=self.request.POST.get('subject'))#, attachments=[('test', self.request.POST.get('file').file.read() ) ])
        message.body = ('%s \n%s \n%s \nhttp://...com/') % (self.request.POST.get('name'), self.request.POST.get('email'), self.request.POST.get('text') )
        message.to='info@....com'
        message.send()
        self.redirect('/customer_service.htm')
```

Comment: "Gets an error message" is not very helpful. Please include the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GAE uploading a file as you have is synonymous with writing it to the blobstore so you need to work with it as such.

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore

upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
blob_info = upload_files[0]
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_info.key())

message.attachments = [blob_info.filename,blob_reader.read()]
```

Once you are done you can always delete it.

```
blob = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_info.key())
blob.delete()
```

Comment: If it is not necessary to store the file, is there another way to do this so the file is automatically deleted, following the attachment to an email? The deletion need not be instantaneous, I am just trying to figure out a way to not have to delete it explicitly. Also, should I use HTML5 file upload (lot of jQuery based choices to implement this) or stick to conventional file upload?

Comment: jQuery is probably simplest - as you say, there are plenty of good examples.  Removing the blob will have to be done explicitly; you could do this asynchronously by sticking the deletion in a function and using the deferred.defer method.